# How to let thread wait for specific other thread to unlock data c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Lets say I have one thread that continuously updates a certain object. During the update, the object must be locked for thread safety.

Now the second thread is more of an event kind of operation. If such a thread is spawned, I'd like the running update to finish it's call and then immediately perform the event operation.

What I absolutely want to avoid is a situation where the event thread needs to wait until it gets lucky to be given computation time at a specific time the update thread doesn't lock up the data it needs to access.

Is there any way I could use the threading/mutex tools in c++ to accomplish this? Or should I save the to-be-done operation in an unlocked var and perform the operation on the update thread?

```
//// System.h
#pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class System {

private:
    int state = 0;
    std::mutex mutex;

public:

    void update();

    void reset(int e);
};
```

```
//////// System.cpp
#include "System.h"

void System::update() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
    state++;
    std::cout << state << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

void System::reset(int e) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
    state = e;
    std::cout << state << std::endl;
}
```

```
////// ThreadTest.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "System.h"

void loop_update(System& system);

void reset_system(System& system);

int main();
```

```
////// ThreadTest.cpp
#include "ThreadTest.h"

void loop_update(System& system) {
    while (true) system.update();
};

void reset_system(System& system) {
    system.reset(0);
};

int main()
{
    System system;
    std::thread t1 = std::thread(loop_update, std::ref(system));

    int reset = 0;

    while (true) {
        
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        std::cout << "Reset" << std::endl;
        reset_system(system);
    }
}
```

Example gives following output. You can clearly see a huge delay in the actual update.

```
1
...
10
Reset
11
...
16
0
1
...
10
Reset
11
...
43
0
1
```

Comment: Use [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Comment: Why do you *sleep* in `System::update()`? Is that an intentional delay, or is it a placeholder for real work? Because if it is an intentional delay, you could move it to the first statement - above the lock - and then you would not be blocking the lock all the time.

Comment: It's a placeholder for intense computation

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have 2 threads using the same mutex. However, you want one thread to get a higher preference than the other to get the actual lock.

As far as I know, there ain't a way to ensure preference using the native tools. You can work around it, if you don't mind the code of both threads knowing about it.

For example:

```
std::atomic<int> shouldPriorityThreadRun{0};

auto priorityThreadCode = [&shouldPriorityThreadRun](){
    ++shouldPriorityThreadRun;
    auto lock = std::unique_lock{mutex};
    doMyStuff();
    --shouldPriorityThreadRun;
};

auto backgroundThreadCode = [&shouldPriorityThreadRun](){
    while (true)
    {
        if (shouldPriorityThreadRun == 0)
        {
           auto lock = std::unique_lock{mutex};
           doBackgroundStuff();
        }
        else
            std::this_thread::yield();
     }
};
```

If you have multiple priority threads, those can't have priority over each other.

If you don't like the yield, you could do fancier stuff with std::condition_variable, so you can inform other threads that the mutex is available. However, I believe it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

it should already work with your current approach.
The mutex is locking concurrent access to your data, so you can lock it within the first thread to update the data.

If the event routine / your second thread comes to execution, it always has to check if the mutex is unlocked. If the mutex is unlocked - and only then, you can lock the mutex and perform the tasks of the second thread.

If I understand your code correctly (i am not a c++ expert), the `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);` seems to be locking the mutex the entire time of the update function...

And therefore other threads merely have time to access the mutex.

Comment: It "works" only in the sense that the state variable is thread safe. But it's super slow as explained in the bottom of the question. I'd like to get it as fast as possible as well.

Answer (score -1):

When the `update` thread finish the job, it needs to unlock the mutex before entering the sleep state, then the `reset` thread could have a chance to take the lock without any delay. I also tried running your codes on my machine and observe it's still waiting for the lock. I don't know when it gets lucky to take the lock. I think in this case it's an UB

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Reset
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18...

void System::update() {
    mutex.lock();
    state++;
    std::cout << state << std::endl;
    mutex.unlock();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

void System::reset(int e) {
    mutex.lock();
    state = e;
    std::cout << state << std::endl;
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: why change the lock_guard in the reset method also?
and why you couldn't leave the guard but inside a new scope?

Comment: @Federico: normally you want to have locks as short as possible.

Comment: @Federico It's fine to leave lock_guard in the scope, I only want to make an example. I will update my answer